# How to add users to redis?

Tags: redis, redisclient, nosql

As my title, I want to add a user who has only read permission to my redis server, like several users in mysql.

However, I just found one way to add password to the default, modify `/etc/redis/redis.conf` file of line `# requirepass foobared`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (up to v3.2) Redis doesn't provide the ability to define users. As you've learned, there's only one user that may be protected with the optional password.